How does co-op work in CotL?
On August 12, co-op came to Cult of the Lamb.
How does this co-op work though? Is it a relatively limited experience, such as in The Binding of Isaac, where the second player is just a ghost following the main player around, and has no agency of their own? Or is it more similar to Minecraft Dungeons, where everyone can do the exact same stuff, and no one is limited?
Essentially, how much freedom does the second player have?
